# close a program completely in c#

Tags: c#

i Have made a program in c# which show 2 types of form 1 is getting values from the user and save it in Database and second is showing those values in a template of crystal report.

My problem is when i move 1st form to 2nd form i hide the first form by using hide(); function and after getting the value on 2nd form from Database i move back to 1st form and hide the second form and show 1st but when i close the whole program it keep running and debugger showing its and running and also have a process in task manager.

I want to know how can i close that background process with the form1 close. sorry for my  bad English.

```
      rollno = txtrollno.Text;
                    ReportCard objreport = new ReportCard();
                    objreport.Show();
                    this.Hide();
```

this is the code for hiding the 1st form .

```
 Form1 objshow = new Form1();
        objshow.Show();
        this.Hide();
```

and in this i hide 2nd and show 1st again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using

```
Close();
```

When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed. You can prevent the closing of a form at run time by handling the Closing event and setting the Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs passed as a parameter to your event handler. If the form you are closing is the startup form of your application, your application ends.

or

```
Application.Exit();
```

This method stops all running message loops on all threads and closes all windows of the application. This method does not force the application to exit. The Exit method is typically called from within a message loop, and forces Run to return. To exit a message loop for the current thread only, call ExitThread .

or

```
Environment.Exit(exitCode)
```

Terminates this process and gives the underlying operating system the specified exit code.  This call requires that you have SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode permissions. If you do not, a SecurityException error occurs.  This is the call to use if you are running a console application.

Comment: i use close in the exit button code but didn't close whole aaplication i will the 2nd option

Comment: Nullifying the object and letting the GC take care of it could be an option too ( not that it's good practice )

Comment: how i let the gc take care of it

Comment: additionally, there is "Environment.Exit" too

Comment: thanks a lot john woo your 2nd suggestion work very fine for me i will be grate full to you

Comment: i want to ask if i get a some suggestion of books for get better practice for my skills in c# any reference

Comment: @jazzb Search for `Professional C# 4.0 and .NET 4`

Comment: `Close` can't be called as soon as he's "done" with the main form.  He needs to close it only after the second form is closed.  Both of the `Exit` methods should only be used in exceptional circumstances, not for regular use of the program.  He simply needs to close the main form at the proper time (which isn't that hard).

Comment: i am trying to mark but it show me to wait 2 mints more for marking and thanks for books i will search them right now . Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

So for your program to end (gracefully) you'll want to close the main form.  Since you are "done" with that form before you want the entire program to end you are currently just hiding it (which is fine) rather than closing it.  What you need to do is ensure that your main form is closed when the second form is closed.  That is easy enough to do with events:

```
Form1 objshow = new Form1();
objshow.Show();
this.Hide();
//Add this next line when you show the second form.
objshow.FormClosed += (_, args) => this.Close();
```